# optimize oracle query for mvc

Tags: oracle, asp.net-mvc-3, odp.net

How can I optimize this oracle query?
It currently takes just under 2 minutes to run, and takes even longer when I execute using ODP in .net MVC3. . .

```
SELECT id FROM (
   SELECT p.id
   FROM account A 
   INNER JOIN person p on p.id = a.id                                                                               
   WHERE a.account LIKE '1%' AND sysdate between a.start_date and a.end_date AND                 
   a.type = 99 AND a.type2 = 88 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT d.id
   FROM account A 
   INNER JOIN dept d on d.account = a.account 
   WHERE a.account like '2%' AND sysdate between d.start_date and d.end_date AND        
   a.type = 100 and a.type2 = 77 
)Q GROUP BY id
```

Account Table structure:

- id: VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)
- account: VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)
- start_date: DATE
- end_date: DATE
- type: VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)
- type2: VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)

Indexes on accountType and deptType (none of the columns used in the query)

DeptTable structure:

- id: VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)
- account: VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)
- start_date: DATE
- end_date: DATE

Indexes on

- account (used in query),
- id (used in query),
- start_date (used in query),
- end_date (used in query),
- deptNum,
- terminationDate

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the tables and the indexes available it's rather difficult to offer more constructive advice. Perhaps you could EDIT THE QUESTION and add this additional information. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis, added. . .. thanks so much for looking and trying to help!

Comment: I just noticed - the join criteria between ACCOUNT and PERSON (first subquery) is ACCOUNT.ID = PERSON.ID. This looks odd to me. Please verify that PERSON.ID is supposed to be used as a foreign key to the ACCOUNT table. And could you add the layout of the PERSON table to your post? And record counts for each of the four tables used in the query would be useful.